# C++ dynamic downcasting of a vector of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, casting

EDIT:

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to implement a deck of card that I could sort by any attribute. Attributes can be integer, double or other types and can either be ''better when smaller'' or ''better when bigger''. The current design I had in mind is using a vector of attributes for Card object and overloading the < operator to be able to sort the cards.

---

I'm trying to figure out a way to downcast shared_ptr elements stored in a vector. I currently need to try all possible types in order to cast to the proper type.

My problem is I want to support many types and my current approach is not very scalable. From what I've read it is impossible to get the type at runtime but I thought there might be a clever way to achieve this with a container class or something similar.

Here's the code I've got so far (see the print_attributes() function in the Card class).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

class AttributeIface{
    //TODO: Why when the class is empty the casts doesnt work??
    public:
        virtual ~AttributeIface() = default;
};

template <typename T>
class AttributeBase : public AttributeIface{
    private:
        T value;
    public:
        AttributeBase(T value):
            value(value){ }

        virtual ~AttributeBase() = default;

        virtual bool operator<(const AttributeBase<T>* &a) const = 0;

        T get_value(void) const{
            return value;
        }

        void print_value(void){
            cout << value << endl;
        }
};

template <typename T>
class AttributeGreaterThan : public AttributeBase<T>{
    public:
        AttributeGreaterThan(T value):
            AttributeBase<T>(value){ }

        bool operator<(const AttributeBase<T>* &a) const{
            return this->get_value() > a->get_value();
        }
};

template <typename T>
class AttributeLessThan : public AttributeBase<T>{
    public:
        AttributeLessThan(T value):
            AttributeBase<T>(value){ }

        bool operator<(const AttributeBase<T>* &a) const{
            return this->get_value() < a->get_value();
        }
};

class Card{
    private:
        vector<tuple<string,shared_ptr<AttributeIface>>> attribute;
    public:
        Card(){
            //TODO: Examples to get rid of
            attribute.push_back(make_tuple("test",
                                           make_shared<AttributeGreaterThan<int>>(123)));
            attribute.push_back(make_tuple("test2",
                                           make_shared<AttributeGreaterThan<double>>(2.3)));
            attribute.push_back(make_tuple("test3",
                                           make_shared<AttributeLessThan<int>>(321)));
            attribute.push_back(make_tuple("test4",
                                           make_shared<AttributeLessThan<double>>(3.4)));
        }

        void print_attributes(void){
            for(tuple<string,shared_ptr<AttributeIface>> &a : attribute){
                //TODO: How can I get rid of these if/elif?
                if(dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeGreaterThan<int>>(get<1>(a))){
                    cout << get<0>(a) << " is a 'gt' int with value => " <<
                        dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeGreaterThan<int>>(get<1>(a))->get_value() << endl;
                }
                else if(dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeGreaterThan<double>>(get<1>(a))){
                    cout << get<0>(a) << " is a 'gt' double with value => " <<
                        dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeGreaterThan<double>>(get<1>(a))->get_value() << endl;
                }
                else if(dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeLessThan<int>>(get<1>(a))){
                    cout << get<0>(a) << " is a 'lt' double with value => " <<
                        dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeLessThan<int>>(get<1>(a))->get_value() << endl;
                }
                else if(dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeLessThan<double>>(get<1>(a))){
                    cout << get<0>(a) << " is a 'lt' double with value => " <<
                        dynamic_pointer_cast<AttributeLessThan<double>>(get<1>(a))->get_value() << endl;
                }
            }
        }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    Card card;
    card.print_attributes();

    return 0;
}
```

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so do not hesitate to tell me if my question is unclear or need more details.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't "dynamic downcasting", but the real real question to which you believe the answer is "dynamic downcasting". This strongly suggestion that you have a design problem, in whatever you're trying to implement, and it's more likely that there is a proper solution that does not involve "dynamic downcasting", and all that headache.

Comment: I can' catch the underlying problem. Your code example is to big to know what is the design idea, the coding problem and the real thing you would achieve. I it really about downcast? Please provide a minimal example and even a more clear description please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use dynamic cast to achieve this. What you can use is a virtual function:

```
class AttributeIface{
    public:
        virtual void print_value() = 0;
};

cout << get<0>(a) << " has value => ";
get<1>(a)->print_value();
cout << '\n';
```

I'll leave as an exercise to print name of the intermediate template.

---

> ```
> //TODO: Why when the class is empty the casts doesnt work??
> ```

Because dynamic casting can only be used with polymorphic types, and if the base has no virtual functions, then it is not polymorphic.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was afraid of... I already have a print_value() function in the full code I'm working on and it works great. However it won't really help me when I'll need to get the value in order to sort a deck of cards based on an attribute. I'll see if I can come up with a new design or if I stick with this approach.

Comment: What does "this" refer to in "You cannot use dynamic cast to achieve this."? The code that OP posted is compilable, so my guess it that the quoted statement is incorrect.

Comment: @JoakimThorén "this" refers to: You cannot dynamic cast into the most derived type without knowing that type beforehand, or without attempting every possibility sequentially and explicitly. Latter being what Antoine wishes to avoid.